# Failed to attach the USB device SEGGER J-Link [0100] to the virtual machine WINDOWS 7

Tags: macos, usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I am running Windows 7 inside Mac OS X with VirtualBox,
I used a BLE inside W7 without any problem. Then I used the BLE USB in the Mac, and when I try to use it again in the W& I got this message:

```
Failed to attach the USB device SEGGER J-Link [0100] to the virtual machine WINDOWS 7.
USB Device 'SEGGER J-Link’ with UUID {} is in use by someone else
```

I unplugged the USB, restart the Mac, start W7, but I can't attach it again to the W7

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I figured it out. You are supposed to:

1. Shutdown the guest
2. Plug in the device, let the host grab it
3. In the host, go to virtual box, and edit the configuration for the guest. In the "Ports" tab, go to USB and add a filter to include the plugged in device
4. Unplug the device
5. Start the guest OS
6. When the guest os is running, plug in the device.

Virtual box will grab the usb device and make it available for the guest. The guest will then go on and try to identify and configure the device.

Done.

Comment: Thank you. On top of that filter, I also had to install [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: Do all like you said, but it doesn't work for me. Every time I plug my device in, Ubunut intercepts this action and notifies about it. And VirtualBox is messaging: "Failed to attache the USB device TS-RDF8 Transcend [002A] to the virtual machine Windows 7". Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005).

Comment: Not working here, host Mac OS, guest Windows 10

Comment: Not working here, host Arch Linux, guest Mac OS

Comment: i can see the device as selected  in Device>USB menu, but can't see in computer folder(disk area)

Comment: My problem was related to VirtualBox. I tried VMWare Workstation Player and everything worked as a charm and the USB was recognized by both Host and Guest.

Answer (score 24):

The solution for me was to install the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.  I had to update virtual box to the latest version then download the latest version of the extension pack.

Then, on the USB tab of the virtual machine settings, I set 'Enable USB Controller' and 'USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller'.  Before it was set to USB 1.1 (OHCI) Controller which did not work.  Then just add a USB filter for the composite device and when I started up the machine again everything worked.

[image: USB Page Image]

Comment: USB 3.0 might be required (it was for me).

Comment: @golmschenk is right, make sure you use the proper USB version

Comment: @golmschenk It worked for me with USB 3.0 and then the guest gave "code 28" error, as Win7 doesn't come with drivers for USB 3.0;  installing generic ones worked, the USB device manufacturer drivers should work too

Comment: This worked for me, as well as adding the device in the filter list.

Comment: @golmschenk, Worked for me, too.

Comment: I've used Virtualbox a lot and never heard of the extension pack ... nice fix

Answer (score 4):

I am using an nRF51-DK Embedded Development Kit from Nordic Semiconductor which has a Segger JLink embedded on the board.  I was having problems getting it to detect on the Mac OS X, Running VirtualBox/Windows 7.

I tried adding a filter under Ports->USB in the Device Image Settings.  The device was coming up as a composite device under USB Devices in Windows 7 Device Manager.

Then I removed the filter, installed the Segger/JLink Driver for Mac, ensured that Mac is picking up the device by running the JLinkExe Utility.  I then proceeded to add a filter in the Ports->USB under the device image and voila! - Windows 7 Picked up Segger/JLink over VirtualBox.

As a side note, I had also installed the Oracle VM Extension Pack for my VirtualBox version from www.virtualbox.org

Answer (score 3):

J-Link debug probe of version 9.3 works perfectly with the VirtualBox(VB) with USB1.1 (without an extension pack). Once I started using the newer J-Link debug probe of version 10.1, the jlink device was not recognized in the VB because the jlink device driver failed to install. This problem was solved with the extension pack for virtualbox. But the extension pack needs a license for long term use so be aware.